# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper in Java 11

Tags: java, jackson

We are using Jackson 2.8.5.tr1 (jackson-databind, jackson-core, jackson-annotations) within our jar file and it works fine using Java 8.
When trying to run our jar file using Java 11, we are getting a runtime exception -

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
```

Any idea why this is happening and how to address this ?
Thanks !

Comment: Did you try upgrading Jackson to 2.9.7?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Not yet.

Comment: Getting the same error after upgrading to Jackson 2.9.7
I do see ObjectMapper class inside jackson-databind -

 inflated: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper$1.class
 inflated: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper$2.class
 inflated: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper$3.class
 inflated: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper$DefaultTypeResolverBuilder.class
 inflated: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper$DefaultTyping.class
 inflated: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.class

Answer (score 1):

The issue was not about Jackson it was about my class loader which didn't work properly on Java 11.
After resolving the class loader issue things work fine using Jackson 2.8.5.

Comment: could you please explain what the error was and how you resolved it? i am facing the same issue

Comment: Older versions of jar-in-jar-loader didn't work with Java 9 and above. Resolved by  updating it - https://github.com/PX4/jMAVSim/pull/79